# Automatically add throws RuntimeException to methods?

Tags: eclipse, runtimeexception

I am using Eclipse and when a method can throw a RuntimeException, then there's no hint from Eclipse, that `throw RuntimeException` is missing after the method signature.

I know that this is intended, because RuntimeException don't have to be handled. However automatically adding `throw RuntimeException` would also include the runtimeException in the javadoc template (the one created by typing `/**`), so I wouldn't forget to documentate the possible RuntimeExceptions.

Any hint on this problem? How to ensure, that I don't forget to document RuntimeExceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to declare a runtime exception because they are unexcepted. If you except to have some exceptions you need to declare it excplicitly in the code by declaring a new exception.

One specific case where you need to declare a method to throws RuntimeException is GWT to handle them correctly in the client side (instead of generic error 500).